# macOS High Sierra changing permissions of file(s) on NAS when opening

Tags: macos, high-sierra, permission, nas

Hopefully some of you Mac gurus can provide a simple and quick answer.
Here's the question: I have a Mac running High Sierra, connected to a primarily Windows network. On that network is a new Seagate NAS 2-Bay. The NAS has two private and one public folders defined. All the other users are using Windows 10 PCs. It appears that whenever the Mac opens a file on the NAS that file becomes unavailable to anyone else once closed.

I have tried many things and at this time am completely stumped. Hopefully someone can provide some ideas/suggestions.

Comment: Which protocol - SMB or NFS?

Comment: Which tool do you use to open this file?

Comment: I am using SMB.   I've also tried the apple file system mount as well but no different.   I can also access the permissions and change it to rw, save it and still no permissions from anyone else.